# PR from one branch to another still shows commits that were already merged in prior PR

Tags: git, azure-devops

I merged a few commits using a PR from Azure Devops from dev to master. 
This completed successfully. 
Later, I added two more commits to dev.
When I now create a new PR from dev to master, it shows the commits (and errors) from the previous PR as well

Retried a couple of times/ refreshed/ relogged in

NA

Expected: New PR has only the two new commits that havent been merged

Comment: May I suggest you do a rebase from the branch you are trying to merge to. For example if you raisinga PR against master, run :
`git rebase master`
fix any conflicts
`git push -f`

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens because you chose the merge type of **Squash commit** when you finished the first pr,this leads to the first pr commits show in your second pr.

When the squash commit merge type is selected to complete pr,the several commits nodes on the topic(dev) branch are merged into one node and merged to the default(master) branch. The original commits node remains on the topic(dev) branch, so when you create the second pr, the first pr's commits and the current commits are displayed.

The reason for the error is the topic branch itself does not have a commit merging it into the default branch. You can refer to this [docs](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Frepos%2Fgit%2Fmerging-with-squash%3Fview%3Dazure-devops%23what-is-a-squash-merge&data=02%7C01%7Cv-hulin%40microsoft.com%7C038bc57ff8df457ff0b308d6eb0994d6%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636954823717808831&sdata=O14Awrv97UAIy5Y%2BjSN6GPxrIPvzby7vClMKNbD4wuQ%3D&reserved=0). I suggest that if you choose squash commit merge type, it is best to check the **Delete source branch after merging** option.

Here is a sample of my reproduce:

I created the first pr and choose Squash commit merge type and there is no check on Delete test607 after merging option
[image]

Then, I crearte the second pr and found that there was a commit of the last pr in this pr.
[image]

After clicking Create, an error occurred.
[image]

Hope this helps.